# A bug concerning _'s

Tags: bug, markdown

[image]

As you can see, it starts bugging up, it's pretty hard to explain it, but look at the picture.

Demo:

**http://url.com/user?u=__username__**

Markdown:

```
**http://url.com/user?u=__username__**
```

Comment: Would be even easier to see if you'd copy/pasted the actual text rather than an image.

Comment: Underscore is reserved in markdownn for italics and not valid in URL anyway.

Comment: Is this for a job posting on eLance?

Comment: I actually already deleted the text in the textbox, and I am too lazy to type it up, but I did take a screenshot. And @random no it's not.

Comment: @random I sure hope it's not for a Stack Overflow question...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18303340/twitter-like-url-but-with-a-s

Comment: Nothing to do with the `*` as far as I can see. I think [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Jtf7R.png) is the smallest possible repro.

Comment: @mat You had to crush my hopes!

Answer (score 9):

If you absolutely have to, you can fix it by escaping an underscore:

**http://url.com/@u=__username__**

```
**http://url.com/@u=\__username__**
```

But you should really be putting that into a code block since it's not something you want people to click.

Comment: I think if some one thinks hard enough, there could be an XSS vulnerability, no?

Comment: I have no idea. Web stuff scares me.

Comment: @user2342080 ummm. no. Where do you get that idea at all? There is nothing here related to causing SO to render scripts.

Comment: Well there is that **">** after *username*, so it could possibly lead to that.

Comment: @user2342080 That's due to a broken attempt to see your mark down as a link. There is no such functionality to make a script tag.

Comment: @Andrew: I do find it disconcerting that it nevertheless creates a partial tag, complete with an unescaped `>`. It might not be too far out of the question for someone with enough time and inclination to figure out a way to get it to output a complete tag and get an `onclick` attribute onto it.

Comment: @icktoofay agree about the general "ick"-yness of it. (see what I did there?)

Comment: Ok, people, seriously. There is no possibility of an XSS attack here. The leftover `">` is a result of the rest of the HTML being stripped. The final result here is `<a href="http://url.com/user?u=<i>_username_</i>">http://url.com/user?u=<i>_username_</i></a>`. When that runs through the final stages, the Markdown parser strips the invalid HTML, meaning that `<a href="http://url.com/user?u=<i>`, the first `</i>`, and the `</a>` at the end all get removed as being invalid. No one can insert an `onclick` or anything of the sort. It *would* get stripped.